# Programmatically acess Google chrome history

Tags: c#, sqlite, google-chrome, .net-3.5, browser-history

I want to index all the user actions and websites in google chrome. i understand that google chrome index all the data in sqlLite database. how can i Programmatically access the chrome web history in my own application

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562092/how-to-access-google-chrome-browser-history-programmatically-on-local-machine.

Comment: I assume you mean .net 3.5 when you say VS 2008. VS is an IDE, not a framework.

Comment: may wonder why? database is locked

Comment: @MeSutPişkin Close chrome before accessing the database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to download the appropriate assembly from the [SqLite downloads page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Once you add a reference to the SQLite assembly, its very similar to standard ADO.net

All the user history is stored in the History database located at the path in the connection string below

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection
    (@"Data Source=C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History");
conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
//  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;";
//  Use the above query to get all the table names
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From urls";
SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
Console.WriteLine(dr[1].ToString());
}
```

Comment: The database is locked exception is thrown

Comment: Same "The Database is locked"

Comment: Maybe the database is locked because an active instance of Chrome is using it, try to copy the file to another location and then read it.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows form application with Datagridview tool - button click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string google = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History";
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        File.Copy(google, Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName);
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource = " + Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName + ";Versio=3;New=False;Compress=True;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            //SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select url,title,visit_count,last_visit_time from urls order by last_visit_time desc", con);
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from urls order by last_visit_time desc", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }
        try // File already open error is skipped
        {
          if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName))
             File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Reference [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4fz7-KQSFY)

Here i have copied the History file to Application startup path in order to avoid SQLite error "database is locked".

Answer (score 0):

Used below code getting "Windows/x86_64" as a result

```
   try 
   {
        Class.forName ("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlite:/C:/Users/tarun.kakkar/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History");

        statement = connection.createStatement ();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM urls");

        while (resultSet.next ()) 
        {
            System.out.println ("URL [" + resultSet.getString ("url") + "]" + ", visit count [" + resultSet.getString ("visit_count") + "]");
        }
    } 

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code might help you:

```
//Use sqlite for read chrome history
using System;

using System.IO;

using System.Linq;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Data.SQLite;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    
{
        
GetChromehistory();

Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void GetChromehistory()
    {
        //Connection string 
        string path = @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History";
        string chromehistorypath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + path;
        if (File.Exists(chromehistorypath))
        {
            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + chromehistorypath + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
            connection.Open();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from urls order by last_visit_time desc", connection);
            connection.Close();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            var allHistoryItems = new List<ChromeHistoryItem>();
            if (dataSet != null && dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 & dataSet.Tables[0] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow historyRow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ChromeHistoryItem historyItem = new ChromeHistoryItem()
                    {
                        URL = Convert.ToString(historyRow["url"]),
                        Title = Convert.ToString(historyRow["title"])
                    };

                    // Chrome stores time elapsed since Jan 1, 1601 (UTC format) in microseconds
                    long utcMicroSeconds = Convert.ToInt64(historyRow["last_visit_time"]);

                    // Windows file time UTC is in nanoseconds, so multiplying by 10
                    DateTime gmtTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(10 * utcMicroSeconds);

                    // Converting to local time
                    DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(gmtTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
                    historyItem.VisitedTime = localTime;

                    allHistoryItems.Add(historyItem);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

public class ChromeHistoryItem

{
    
public string URL { get; set; }
    
public string Title { get; set; }
    
public DateTime VisitedTime { get; set; }

}
```