# Access chrome settings ( history , extensions,settings ,about ) using windows applications in c#

Tags: c#

how to access chrome settings using c# windows applications?
1.history 
2.extensions
3.settings 
4.about

Main intention is to access "LAN settings" through this windows application.

Comment: You can check the answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608200/programmatically-acess-google-chrome-history.

Comment: Post what you tried

Comment: hai chandrashekar.thanks for u r concern

Comment: but i am new to this tool and i am good in serial communication .So to start with can u suggest me the procedure to access.Rest i will take care of that