# Get downloadhistory from Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium, python-2.x

Is there any way I can find out what the latest file Selenium downloaded was, and from where (what URL) it was downloaded?

I am fetching files from a large number of sites (that I do not control) by clicking on elements, and my problem is that I do not know how the files are downloaded. Sometimes it is just an `<a>` element, sometimes there is a Javascript event attached to some element, or form (not always obvious from inspection), and so on, and so on.
So I though the easiest would be to just do my clicks, and then check what landed in the download folder. But then I have no idea *where that file came from*, and I also need to store the url.

For files that can be displayed inline, I can, of course, open them in the browser and get the `driver.current_url`. This is very convenient for file formats where it actually works, so if there is a way to force e.g. Firefox or Chrome to open *all* files inline, that would also be an option. (I am aware of [one such extension](https://github.com/spasche/openinbrowser). That extension, however, requires some user interaction in a OS file dialogue window, and that seems like overkill here)

### Possible solutions

- **Firefox**: [Read `moz_downloads` from `downloads.sqlite`](https://evilzone.org/scripting-languages/(python)-firefox-forensic-script-(pass-history-cookies)/), in the FF SQLite DB
- **Chrome**: [Read the corresponding SQLite db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562092/how-to-access-google-chrome-browser-history-programmatically-on-local-machine) for Chrome/ium
- Write [browser extensions](https://github.com/spasche/openinbrowser) that modifies the mimetype of visited pages, so that all files are opened as plain in the browser, and the URLs can be accessed from there.

Answer (score 1):

How I understanding selenium it only insert js to page, that mean that you can interact only with web page but not with browser futures.

But you can do like in this post [How to access Google Chrome browser history programmatically on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562092/how-to-access-google-chrome-browser-history-programmatically-on-local-machine) if that files are in download history you can find them there.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it that example, don't I already have to know the url of the file I want to download?

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download and attach with file in you download folder.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned in the Q, but it's not my server... Added that info now

Comment: Now that's something! I'll give it a try. If you update your answer I'll upvote it!